# GET/POST request via AT Commands

Tags: esp8266, arduino-ide, http, espressif

I am trying to send a simple GET/POST request to a dummy end point on https://requestbin.com/. I am using an ESP8266 module. I am using the arduino serial monitor to send these AT commands. I connect to wifi and then use the following AT commands

```
AT+CIPSTART="TCP","54.166.71.140 ",443  (the IP address from requestbin)
```

I then do

```
AT+CIPSEND=80
```

followed by

```
GET / HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: fc35001f8ec49962d182320446070d.m.pipedream.net\r\n\r\n
```

I get the output as follows

```
Recv 80 bytes

SEND OK

+IPD,272:HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server: awselb/2.0
Date: Mon, 07 Dec 2020 13:28:01 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 122
Connection: close

<html>
<head><title>400 Bad Request</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
</body>
</html>
CLOSED
```

Is there problem with the length of CIPSEND or the format of the request itself.

Comment: the \r\n are send as \r\n, not as new line characters

Comment: how should the At command look like in that case ?

Comment: send first `GET / HTTP/1.0`, then `Host: fc35001f8ec49962d182320446070d.m.pipedream.net` and then an empty line. do it fast before the connection times out

Comment: what would be the value for CIPSEND in this case ?

Comment: the count should include the new line charcaters. \r as 1 and \n as 1 character

Comment: Is there an easier way to calculate how long the AT+CIPSEND value should be ? i still get bad request.

Comment: bad request is a response from the server, so it can connect and receive the response. that is a good test. now write the code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117028/discussion-between-omkar-joglekar-and-juraj).